# ReportViewer Control and a Medium Trust Server

Tags: asp.net, reportviewer, medium-trust

I have a couple of websites with the same hoster that have been setup with 2 different trust levels. One is 'Full' and the other is 'Medium'. I did not realise this because the hoster decided to implement a new security policy and not tell anyone. I only found out when I tried to use the ReportViewer control like I had on the other, older site. Now obviously I am getting the following error message:

> Security Exception
>
> Description: The application attempted
>   to perform an operation not allowed by
>   the security policy.  To grant this
>   application the required permission
>   please contact your system
>   administrator or change the
>   application's trust level in the
>   configuration file.
>
> Exception Details:
>   System.Security.SecurityException:
>   That assembly does not allow partially
>   trusted callers.

Now what I am wondering is there a way to use the ReportViewer control in a medium trust environment. I've tried reading about this on MSDN but to be honest trying to make head or tails out of Microsoft's documentation has never been something I could get to grips with.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen posts that say the Viewer Control will only work in medium trust if you are running in 'remote' mode (as opposed to 'local' mode). I'm also looking for some good code samples on how to do this, and what versions of SQL Server and Visual Studio are required.